# asio ssl content is unreadable

Tags: ssl, boost-asio

I'm using boost asio to read content of different websites (all ssl).
On some sites, my code is working and i'm getting the correct content.
Others, like google will give me headers, but the content is rubbish (i will post an example at the end).

```
asio::io_service svc;
context_(asio::ssl::context::sslv23_client);
socket(svc, context);
context.set_default_verify_paths();

asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(svc_);
asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("www.google.de", "https");
asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

socket.set_verify_mode(asio::ssl::context::verify_none);

asio::connect(socket.next_layer(), endpoint_iterator);
socket.handshake(asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket>::client);

// Building request_buffer..
// ...
asio::write(socket, request_buffer);

// reading content
while(asio::read(socket, stream_buffer, asio::detail::transfer_at_least_t(1))) {
    std::cout<< &response_buffer;
}
```

This is a sample of my code. I think, my problem is the connection. If not, i can post the full code.

Response example:
`12b3
       ╝<╔r9ûg+ó ª]-ÆÖ$ôï,▒CÂeùª╝¿-òË╚Iÿ╣5Ç%MÈe>óOÐù:╬╣NuËƒ╠ù╠{@«dJJRvD'æ└█­­VðçO_}xy±ƒg'dí|o|êƒ─ú┴³¿ß▓µ½ô1ÛÄ}ª(Öåübü:j(vÑ┌8¸9Ö.¿ÉL┼jÍ6 îèÜý1┐<j╝4ËøÎk┤7ax,Zä;`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like compressed content transferred with Content-Encoding chunked. If you look at the HTTP header (which you must have read in code not shown) you will probably find:

```
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Content-Encoding: gzip
```